# Accessing Hashmap from multiple threads without synchronization

Tags: java, multithreading, hashmap

I have a HashMap that I need multiple threads to access. My design is such that each thread will be reading and writing to its own entry in the map: the same map, but no two threads work on the same entry. No one thread will ever need to iterate over the map or call `size()`. So my question is: do I have to synchronize on the Hashmap or may I just use it with confidence that it will never throw a ConcurrentModificationException? My obvious worry is that synchronizing will create a huge bottleneck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So my question is: do I have to synchronize on the Hashmap or may I just use it with confidence that it will never throw a ConcurrentModificationException?

You should use `ConcurrentHashMap` for this purpose.  The issue is not *just* about iterating but it is also about memory synchronization.

> ... each thread will be reading and writing to its own entry in the map ...

This is someone ambiguous.  If your `HashMap` is static in that the threads are only *reading* from the map and only making changes to the object that is referenced in the map but *not* changing the value in the map then you will be fine.  You can initialize your map *before* the threads are started and they can use the map without memory synchronization.

However, if one thread changes the map in any manner to point to a new object, it must publish that change to central memory and other threads must see those updates.  That requires memory synchronization on both the reading and writing sides.

> My obvious worry is that synchronizing will create a huge bottleneck.

This smacks of premature optimization.  Most likely you will be limit by IO long before contention over the map is an issue.  In any case, switching to use a `ConcurrentHashMap` will alleviate your worries and it will be a minimal performance decrease compared to a non-synchronized map.

Comment: I wish you hadn't pointed me in the bottleneck direction. But you make sense. Thanks. I will accept in 7mins